# Implementing own quicksort on dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, dynamic, quicksort

I have to implement my own sort on a dynamic string array, e.g. of such array is:

```
string * sortArray;
```

I then read in the size of the array from a text file and make the array as long as needed and fill it. So, I have...

```
sortArray = new string[_numberOfNames];

for(int i = 0; i < _numberOfNames; ++i){
    sin >> _data[i];
}
```

Now I need to create my own sorting method and I thought I'd go with quicksort. My problem is, I'm not sure how to go about it.

When I choose a pivot, how can I then go about setting up two more dynamic string arrays to put the lower values and highers values in to, then recurse on? There is no way of knowing before hand how big each array needs to be before I start putting values into them.

I thought I could do something like define the size of each array as being the same as the array being sorted, and then some how remove any unwanted empty spaces from the end, but I'm not sure this is possible?

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I know about the std::sort, I already have this in the program, I'm just trying to implement a sort myself.

Comment: why don't you use std::vector where you have variable sizes?

Comment: Quick sort is done inplace. You don't need to create additional arrays.

Comment: try to use use std::vector, not an array.

Comment: also if you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort you will see that there is an "In place" version of the algorithm which doesn't require extra memory.

Comment: You do not set up two additional arrays. You partition the original array in-place. This means you shuffle the elements within the array such that lower values at at the lower end, and higher values are at the higher end. Look at the wikipedia article to see how it's done. There are even youtube videos.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I had used std::vector to start with but (this is for uni work) I was told it's not what the academic staff are looking for. 
I'll give the inplace a go :)
thanks again.

Comment: Hey guys, I tried implementing the in-place quicksort algorithm going off the pseudo-code on the wiki page and here is what I have come up with: [link]http://pastebin.com/nqPMUf0Y it works for the most part but there are a few anomalies in the sorted data. My best bet is something to do with when I'm putting the pivot back into it's place, but I can't figure out where I've gone wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Two options as from the comments above:

1.) Use std::vector. There you can have variable size arrays.

2.) Use an "in place" version of quicksort that does the sorting in your original array. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have array size `N`
and you pivot value is `x`

what you should do is like that, have two pointers one to the beginning(0) and one to the end (N-1). they should both move to the middle. when ever the beginning pointer value is greater than `x` and the end pointer value is lower than `x` switch their values. after you finished and placed `x` in his new location (where the two pointers met) continue recursionally for the part left to `x` and right to `x`.